# A line intersects a hyperbola at the points $(-2,-6)$ and $(4,2)$ and one of the asymptotes of the hyperbola at $(1,-2)$. Find the centre.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> A line intersects a hyperbola at the points $(-2,-6)$ and $(4,2)$. It also intersects one of the asymptotes of the hyperbola at the point $(1,-2)$.
>   Find the centre of the hyperbola.

My approach:

The mid-point of the two points of contact $(-2,-6)$ and $(4,2)$ is the point $(1,-2)$ and we are given that the line cuts the asymptote at this point. Hence the answer is $(1,-2)$. But this seems intuitive and I am not sure whether my reasoning is correct. I am looking for another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition can be stated as the proposition below:

> If $A$ and $B$ are two different points on a hyperbola and the midpoint of $AB$ lies on the asymptotes, then this midpoint is the center of the hyperbola.

*Proof:* Note that this proposition is irrelevant to coordinate systems, thus without loss of generality, the hyperbola can be assumed to be $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.

Suppose the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ are $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, respectively, then $x_1, x_2 ≠ 0$ and$$
\frac{x_1^2}{a^2} - \frac{y_1^2}{b^2} = 1, \quad \frac{x_2^2}{a^2} - \frac{y_2^2}{b^2} = 1. \tag{1}
$$
Because the asymptotes are $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 0$ and $\left( \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \dfrac{y_1 + y_2}{2} \right)$ lies on the asymptotes, then$$
\frac{(x_1 + x_2)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y_1 + y_2)^2}{b^2} = 0. \tag{2}
$$

Now, suppose $x_1 + x_2 ≠ 0$, then $y_1 + y_2 ≠ 0$ by (2). From (1) there is$$
\frac{x_1^2 - x_2^2}{a^2} = \frac{y_1^2 - y_2^2}{b^2},
$$
and from (2) there is$$
\frac{(x_1 + x_2)^2}{a^2} = \frac{(y_1 + y_2)^2}{b^2},
$$
thus\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{\Longrightarrow}}{} \frac{x_1 - x_2}{x_1 + x_2} = \frac{\dfrac{x_1^2 - x_2^2}{a^2}}{\dfrac{(x_1 + x_2)^2}{a^2}} = \frac{\dfrac{y_1^2 - y_2^2}{b^2}}{\dfrac{(y_1 + y_2)^2}{b^2}} = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{y_1 + y_2}\\
&\Longrightarrow \frac{2x_1}{x_1 + x_2} = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{x_1 + x_2} + 1 = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{y_1 + y_2} + 1 = \frac{2y_1}{y_1 + y_2}\\
&\Longrightarrow \frac{y_1}{x_1} = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{x_1 + x_2} \Longrightarrow \frac{y_1}{x_1} = \frac{y_2}{x_2} := c.
\end{align*}
Note that $x_1 + x_2 ≠ 0$, plugging $y_1 = cx_1$ and $y_2 = cx_2$ into (2) to get $\dfrac{1}{a^2} - \dfrac{c^2}{b^2} = 0$, then by (1) there is$$
1 = \frac{x_1^2}{a^2} - \frac{y_1^2}{b^2} = \left( \frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{c^2}{b^2} \right) x_1^2 = 0,
$$
a contradiction. Therefore, $x_1 + x_2 = 0$, which implies $y_1 + y_2 = 0$ by (2). Hence the midpoint of $AB$ is the center $(0, 0)$ of the hyperbola.

Comment: Actually it is only mentioned that the midpoint lies on one of the asymptotes and not both of them, how do we know it lies on both of them? Also, the midpoint of AB is (1,-2) right? How can it become (0,0)? Please do explain this to me.

Comment: @Hema The equation $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=0$ incorporates both asymptotes, so no need to distinguish. As is stated in the first line of the proof, it's irrelevant to coordinate systems and when the hyperbola is assumed to be $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, its center is $(0,0)$.

Comment: Actually I started the bounty today, so I am not allowed to award it until tomorrow, I will be giving it tomorrow, thank you so much.

Comment: @Hema It's OK, and thank you the same :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ symmetric matrix and let $u_1^TAu_1=u_2^TAu_2=1$. Then
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\left(\frac{u_1-u_2}{2}\right)^TA\left(\frac{u_1-u_2}{2}\right)}_{P_1}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{u_1+u_2}{2}\right)^TA\left(\frac{u_1+u_2}{2}\right)}_{P_2}=1~~,\tag{1}
\end{align}
which implies that if $P_2$ above is zero, then $P_1=1$.

Any hyperbola (rotated or not) centered in the origin can be defined as the points $\vec{x}$ such that $x^TAx=1$ for A symmetric$^*$, and the asymptotes as those point such that $x^TAx=0$. In Equation (1), $u_1$ and  $u_2$ are in the hyperbola. Midpoint is $(u_1+u_2)/2$, which being in the asymptote means $P_2=0$. Therefore, $P_1=1$ or $(u_1-u_2)/2$ is in the hyperbola. But if $u_2$ is in the hyperbola (centered in origin) so it is $-u_2$. Therefore, we have that $u_1$, $-u_2$, and  $(u_1-u_2)/2$ are in the hyperbola, which is impossible unless $(u_1-u_2)/2=u_1$ or $=-u_2$ (a line intersects hyperbola at most in two points). In either case, $u_1+u_2=0$ or, what is the same, the midpoint between these two points is the origin.

Reasoning above can be taken outside origin taking the equation for the hyperbola as $(x-x_0)^TA(x-x_0)=1$ and the asymptotes $(x-x_0)^TA(x-x_0)=0$.

$^*$ $A$ must have one eigenvalue positive and one negative, but it is not necessary for this proof.